# How to estimate scrapy performance

Tags: python, performance, scrapy

## Problem

Hi there. I'm trying to figure out how to estimate target optimal Scrapy performance in order to not overtune things. I prepared an example scrapy project with a spider that crawls all 1000 book pages from https://books.toscrape.com. I expected much better performance then I got. What is wrong? My calculations or my spider?

## Expected and actual results

Average download latency according to the spider log is  around 160ms (see log excerpt below). I use 16 concurrent requests with 2 seconds of download delay between the requests. I also disabled randomized download delay to simplify calculations. I didn't enable any pipelines therefore all the processing is only in the spider (populating items). To gather all the items I need to issue 1000 request for all book pages plus 50 requests for listings.

Estimated throughput = 16 requests/(2s+0.160s)=7.4 req/s

**Estimated time = total_requests/estimated_throughput= 1050/7.4 = 141.89s**

**Actual time is around 30 minutes.**

## Charts

[image]

[image: Downloader is fully utilized]
As you can see from the second chart downloader is fully utilized throughout the crawl.

## Spider code

```
import datetime
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from books_toscrape_com.items import BookItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from itemloaders.processors import MapCompose, Join
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import logging


class BaseSpider(Spider):
    name = 'base'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['https://books.toscrape.com/']
    # Setup spider logging
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(ch)
    fh = logging.FileHandler('logs/books_to_scrape_base.log')
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fh)

    def parse(self, response):
        """Get links to book pages and pagination links"""
        book_page_links = response.\
            xpath('//article[@class="product_pod"]/div[@class="image_container"]/a/@href').getall()
        pagination_links = response.xpath('//ul[@class="pager"]/li[@class="next"]/a/@href').getall()
        yield from response.follow_all(urls=book_page_links, callback=self.parse_book, priority=1)
        yield from response.follow_all(urls=pagination_links, callback=self.parse, priority=100)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        """Parse book pages"""
        # self.logger.info('Parse book function called on %s', response.url)
        self.logger.info('Download latency is %s', response.meta.get('download_latency'))
        l = ItemLoader(item=BookItem(), response=response)
        l.add_xpath('name', '//article[@class="product_page"]/div[@class="row"]/descendant::h1/text()')
        l.add_xpath('description', '/html/head/meta[@name="description"]/@content')
        l.add_xpath('price',
                    '//article[@class="product_page"]/div[@class="row"]/descendant::p[@class="price_color"]/text()')

        l.add_xpath('availability',
                    '//article[@class="product_page"]/div[@class="row"]/descendant::p[@class="instock availability"]/'
                    'text()')
        l.add_xpath('availability_count',
                    '//article[@class="product_page"]/div[@class="row"]/descendant::p[@class="instock availability"]/'
                    'text()')
        l.add_xpath('image_urls', '//article[@class="product_page"]/div[@class="row"]/descendant::img/@src',
                    MapCompose(lambda i: urljoin(response.url, i)))
        l.add_xpath('breadcrumbs',
                    '//ul[@class="breadcrumb"]/li/a/text()',
                    Join('|'))

        l.add_value('url', response.url)
        l.add_value('project', self.settings.get('BOT_NAME'))
        l.add_value('spider', self.name)
        l.add_value('datetime', datetime.datetime.now())

        return l.load_item()
```

## Settings

```
BOT_NAME = 'books_toscrape_com'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['books_toscrape_com.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'books_toscrape_com.spiders'
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 16
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2
RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY = False
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 100000
COOKIES_ENABLED = False

EXTENSIONS = {
'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats': 50,
'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage': None,
'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats': None,
'books_toscrape_com.extensions.custom_logstats.LogStatsCustom': 100,
}

AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = False
AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES = [301]
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'

RETRY_ENABLED = False
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 15
DUPEFILTER_DEBUG = True
CUSTOM_LOGSTATS_INTERVAL = 1
```

## Versions

```
python = "^3.8"
Scrapy = "^2.5.1"
```

## Download latency log excerpt

```
2022-02-21 16:09:03,263 - books_toscrape_com.spiders.base - INFO - Download latency is 0.16035914421081543
2022-02-21 16:09:05,264 - books_toscrape_com.spiders.base - INFO - Download latency is 0.16113996505737305
2022-02-21 16:09:09,266 - books_toscrape_com.spiders.base - INFO - Download latency is 0.16111087799072266
2022-02-21 16:09:11,266 - books_toscrape_com.spiders.base - INFO - Download latency is 0.16047191619873047
```

Answer (score 0):

As I was provided with an answer via [link](https://t.me/scrapy_python) that if DOWNLOAD_DELAY specified then requests are going to be sent no more than once per 2.16 seconds. Which is the same as sending them in single thread.

I double-checked this using mitmproxy and confirmed it.
[image]